# @EntityListeners configured from container

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, entitylisteners

I have a EntityListener that needs to be configurable (typical data source info: driver, user, password), but I´d like to avoid adding one more properties file to the project. Is there any way to retrieve from some standard configuration place such as web.xml? It seems that injection via @Resource will be only available in JPA 2.1 (I am using JPA 2.0).

UPDATE - to make this clear

In my entity bean, I have an annotation @EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class). So MyEntityListener may have methods annotated with @PostPersist for example. When my entity bean is gonna be persisted, this method is called. What I want is to retrieve the data for MyEntityListener initialization without using another configuration file.

Comment: EntityListener not really need to be defined in a configuration file, just add @EntityListener, are asking for EntityManagerFactory ? , because it require the datasource, etc... Also in orm.xml you can define default entity listeners.

Comment: @Koitoer more details in the question

Comment: If you are using spring you could use @Value to pass some initialization params to your bean . Are you using spring ?.  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html

Comment: no I am not using spring :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/openjpa/audit/Auditor.html does the trick. It works (my bad, it was a misconfiguration of mine). Actually it works pretty well.

```
<property name="openjpa.Auditor" value="com.acme.Auditor(param2=10,param2='hello')"/>
```